# Powershell CSV script Faster

Tags: powershell, csv

I am looking to make my script a lot faster and giving me an output faster. I am dealing with large sets of data in my csv, and it takes around an hour if I put in the full file to complete with the script.

```
 $csv = Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' |
Where-Object {($_.Name0 -eq "administrators") -and ($_.caption0 -match "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Professional|Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8 Pro|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro")} |
  Select-Object "Netbios_name0", "Name0", "Account0","category0","Domain0","Unique Account Name","Type0","caption0", "Excluded"
#Modify each line
Foreach ($row in $csv) {
If ($row.Type0 -eq 'Domain') { 
    $row."Unique Account Name" = "$($row.Domain0) - $($row.Account0)" 
    If ($row."Unique Account Name" -in @('ACCOUNTS - DODSCAN'.'ACCOUNTS - Domain Admins','ACCOUNTS - LADM_WS_Admins','ACCOUNTS - Tech Enterprise'))
         {$row."Excluded" = "True"}
    Else {$row."Excluded" = "False"}        
}
Else {
    $row."Unique Account Name" = "$($row.Netbios_name0) - $($row.Account0)"
    If ($row."Account0" -in @('esrxadm1n_esi','#Update','medco_tech','medco_admin'))
         {$row."Excluded" = "True"}
    Else {$row."Excluded" = "False"}
}
    Write-Host $row."Unique Account Name"
    Write-Host $row."Excluded"    
}

#Export CSV
 $csv | Export-Csv U:\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm)-TestOutput1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Can anyone help me make it faster?

Comment: This would be a better post on CodeReview rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you @BenH

Comment: How many rows does this file have?

Comment: Why do you use two foreach loops?

Comment: That isn't all that large. Perhaps the `Write-Host` commands could write to a file instead. In any event, posting the question on [codereview.se] rather than here does sound like a good suggestion. I don't know enough `PowerShell` to answer your question.

Comment: @JohnColeman Sorry that was the wrong number it is usually around 330k.

Comment: Even 330k isn't all that much. Nothing that explains 60 minutes of run-time for code which seems to be `O(n)` in the number of rows. Printing to a console is slow. If the bottleneck isn't all of those `Write-Host` commands then I have no idea what it is. Hopefully someone at [codereview.se] (where working code is improved) would know.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have not posted it there yet

Comment: What you can do to find out where the bottleneck is to use a timer object at the start of the script and output the elapsed times at different parts of your code to determine where the biggest hangup is.  Also, since your arrays that you're checking with your -in clause have no variable information in them, move them to static arrays outside of your loops to reference as variables.  There's no point in recreating them 660K times if they're completely static.

Comment: Also, if you have 330K rows in a CSV and a large number of columns, I'd bet your import-csv and filtering is the biggest bottleneck.  The powershell process is probably in excess of multiple GBs and if your system is paging, will be responsible for the overhwelming majority of this time...

Answer (score 1):

Examples of what I was talking about in comments:

```
$t = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
$t.Start()

$arr1 = @('ACCOUNTS - DODSCAN'.'ACCOUNTS - Domain Admins','ACCOUNTS - LADM_WS_Admins','ACCOUNTS - Tech Enterprise')
$arr2 = @('esrxadm1n_esi','#Update','medco_tech','medco_admin')

$csv = Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' | Where-Object {($_.Name0 -eq "administrators") -and ($_.caption0 -match "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Professional|Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8 Pro|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro")} | Select-Object "Netbios_name0", "Name0", "Account0","category0","Domain0","Unique Account Name","Type0","caption0", "Excluded"
Write-Host "Took $($t.Elapsed)ms to load and filter the CSV"

#Modify each line
Foreach ($row in $csv) {
If ($row.Type0 -eq 'Domain') { 
    $row."Unique Account Name" = "$($row.Domain0) - $($row.Account0)" 
    If ($row."Unique Account Name" -in $arr1)
         {$row."Excluded" = "True"}
    Else {$row."Excluded" = "False"}        
}
Else {
    $row."Unique Account Name" = "$($row.Netbios_name0) - $($row.Account0)"
    If ($row."Account0" -in $arr2)
         {$row."Excluded" = "True"}
    Else {$row."Excluded" = "False"}
}
    Write-Host $row."Unique Account Name"
    Write-Host $row."Excluded"    
}

#Export CSV
 $csv | Export-Csv U:\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm)-TestOutput1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I tried yours and when I ran it, it still took 54 minutes for the whole file. The one I did takes 49

Comment: What was the emitted time for the file load?

Comment: As in from creation of the file to the end of the script?

Comment: As in, I showed you how to create a timer object so you could see how you might be able to time out the different sections of your script.  The example I gave was to emit the time it took immediately after you load and filter the CSV.  My suspicion is that this will be the majority of the time.  You can see it in the "Write-Host" immediately following your $csv assignment.

Answer (score 1):

And if you put all in the same line like this?

```
$tab1 = @('ACCOUNTS - DODSCAN', 'ACCOUNTS - Domain Admins','ACCOUNTS - LADM_WS_Admins','ACCOUNTS - Tech Enterprise')
$tab2 = @('esrxadm1n_esi','#Update','medco_tech','medco_admin')

Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' | Select "administrators", "Netbios_name0", "Name0", "Account0","category0","Domain0","Unique Account Name","Type0","caption0", "Excluded" | %{

 if ($_.Name0 -eq "administrators" -and $_.caption0 -match "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Professional|Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8 Pro|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro")
 {
    If ($_.Type0 -eq 'Domain') 
    { 
        $_."Unique Account Name" = "$($_.Domain0) - $($_.Account0)"
        $_."Excluded" = $_."Unique Account Name" -in $tab1   
    }
    Else 
    {
        $_."Unique Account Name" = "$($_.Netbios_name0) - $($_.Account0)"
        $_."Excluded" = $_."Account0" -in $tab2
    }

  $_

}

} | Export-Csv U:\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm)-TestOutput1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Unfortunately yours did not run when I put it in the powershell.

Comment: I added in the Unique Account Name, so it is giving me the following error because it is saying it is not in there.Exception setting "Unique Account Name": "The property 'Unique Account Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
At line:10 char:55
+         $_."Unique Account Name" = "$($_.Domain0) - $($_.Account0)"
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException

Comment: Ok you have created this property into your select, i dont have seen that. Try my modified code please

Comment: I just tried it and it ran but it did not produce out any output into my CSV. It stayed at 0 kb

Comment: Sorry, try again

Comment: I am running it as we speak, so far it has taken 4 mins to get to 1000kb and the file is just over 13000kb. So if i had to estimate the time, yours would take around 50 mins. Also compared to my original the excluded True and Falses are not the same.

Comment: If you want a really true / false i will modify my code

Comment: Your drive U:\ is a local drive or a Network drive? If its network drive try to copy in local (c:\temp by example and use your script in local, exit file too)

Comment: That would be great, is their anything else I can try to make this faster? The CSV that I am importing is around 33000kb

Comment: What about drive u:\ ? Otherwise, i dont have solution, except use compiled langage like C# or C

Comment: How are extracct your csv? With database?

Comment: I am going to try putting it in  a local drive

Comment: If your datas are builded by database, you can may be export your datas whith an SQL query with 'case' instruction wich build your colum?

Comment: I just put in the local drive and it only took a few minutes now. Would you be able to switch it so the True and False are the same as my code above?

Comment: that's what i thought ;) I have modified my code for true/false error

Comment: you want only 'Unique Account Name' and 'Excluded' into your output?

Comment: No, the way I have it is great, but it still is not matching up with what I have in my first code on top. The True and Falses are different for some reason?

Comment: Result is different or its write with an other method?

Comment: It is written differently or there is the wrong value when there should be true?

Comment: The result is different

Comment: you have 'ACCOUNTS - DODSCAN'.'ACCOUNTS - Domain Admins' and i have 'ACCOUNTS - DODSCAN', 'ACCOUNTS - Domain Admins' its a difference (you use '.' i use ',')  What do you want as character between the two? I suppose its a mistake of you no?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having 2 Foreach blocks looping on the same object ($row in $csv), why don't you just combine them? If your CSV is large, why go through it twice?

```
Foreach ($row in $csv) {
If ($row.Type0 -eq 'Domain') { 
    $row."Unique Account Name" = "$($row.Domain0) - $($row.Account0)" 
    Write-Host $row."Unique Account Name"
} Else { 
    $row."Unique Account Name" = "$($row.Netbios_name0) - $($row.Account0)"
 }
If (($row.Type0 -eq 'Local') -and ($row.Account0 -in @('esrxadm1n_esi','#Update','medco_tech','medco_admin')) -and ($row."Unique Account Name" -in @('ACCOUNTS - DODSCAN'.'ACCOUNTS - Domain Admins','ACCOUNTS - LADM_WS_Admins','ACCOUNTS - Tech Enterprise')))  { 
    $row."Excluded" = "True" 
    Write-Host $row."Excluded"
 } Else { 
    $row."Excluded" = "False" 
 }
}
```

Also, where you do this match at the top:

```
($_.caption0 -match "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Professional|Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8 Pro|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro")
```

Would you be able to reduce it to `$_.caption0 -match "Microsoft Windows \d{1,2}"` without it picking up rows you don't want, or is that out of the picture?

Comment: That is kind of out of the picture since we do not want the Microsoft Windows Servers in there

Answer (score 0):

I have a ~600k line CSV of event logs here, and I can test:

```
import-csv events.csv | select * | foreach { $_ } | Export-csv out.csv
```

and it takes 5 minutes 15 seconds (~180Mb / on an SSD). With a `write-host` it pushes up to 9 mins 36 seconds. So it's maybe something about your CSV being HUGE (lots of info per row?), loading it all into memory at once? or the write-host lines.

Try changing it to a streaming approach:

```
Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' |
    Where-Object {

        ($_.Name0 -eq "administrators") -and
        ($_.caption0 -match "Microsoft Windows (10 Enterprise|7 Enterprise|7 Professional|8 Enterprise|8 Pro|8.1 Enterprise|8.1 Pro)")

    } | ForEach-Object { 

        If ($row.Type0 -eq 'Domain')
        {
            $row."Unique Account Name" = $row.Domain0 + ' - ' + $row.Account0
            $row."Excluded" = ($row."Unique Account Name" -in @('ACCOUNTS - DODSCAN'.'ACCOUNTS - Domain Admins','ACCOUNTS - LADM_WS_Admins','ACCOUNTS - Tech Enterprise'))
        }
        Else
        {
            $row."Unique Account Name" = $row.Netbios_name0 + ' - ' + $row.Account0
            $row."Excluded" = ($row."Account0" -in @('esrxadm1n_esi','#Update','medco_tech','medco_admin'))
        }

    } | Select-Object "Netbios_name0", "Name0", "Account0",
                      "category0","Domain0","Unique Account Name",
                      "Type0","caption0", "Excluded" |
    Export-Csv U:\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm)-TestOutput1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I also shuffled around some of the redundant "if (thing test is true) then (true) else if (thing test is false) then (false)" into just "(thing test)", removed subexpressions, shortened the regex a bit, and moved the select to the end on the guideline 'filter early, select late'.

But making it significantly faster than a PS approach is going to involve dropping the CSV processing from PowerShell down to .Net, or treating it as a text file and doing some filtering that way first, or something.